# How to check existing session is invalidated or not?

Tags: java, session

How can i check existing session is invalidated or not?
In the following loginBean code i checked every login the user already loggedin or not. 
If already loggedin by other system, deactivate that session and creating new. if that session was invalidated by time out, next time userSessionMap contain usedname and error to invalidate. so how to check it is invalidated?

```
Map appMap = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getApplicationMap();
Map<String, HttpSession> userSessionMap = (Map<String, HttpSession>) appMap.get("USERS");

if (userSessionMap.containsKey(getUsername())) {
log.info(getUsername() + " already loggedin. Closing existing sesssion");
HttpSession sess = userSessionMap.get(getUsername());
sess.invalidate();
}
```

Comment: If you don't have a request, what does "session" mean to you? Are you talking about an application container context like Tomcat? Or is this session something you wrote?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try passing `false` as the parameter to the [getSession(boolean)](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getSession(boolean)) . This will give back a session if it exists or else it will return `null`.

```
HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);
if (session == null || !request.isRequestedSessionIdValid()) {
    //comes here when session is invalid.        
}
```

> Returns the current HttpSession associated with this request or, if there is no current session and create is true, returns a new session.
> If create is **false** and the request has no valid HttpSession, this method returns **null.**

Comment: I dont have request here.

Map appMap = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getApplicationMap();
        Map<String, HttpSession> userSessionMap = (Map<String, HttpSession>) appMap.get("USERS");

Comment: is `request.getSession(true)` equivalent to `request.getSession()`?

Answer (score 12):

`HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);` will give `IllegalStateException` if the [session is already invalidated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5831960/request-getsessionfalse-cause-null-pointer-exception)

```
boolean invalidated = false;
try {
    request.getSession(false);
} catch(IllegalStateException ex) {
    invalidated = true;
}
```